# Response issue with RESTful API using OpenRasta

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, openrasta

I am implementing RESTful API using OpenRasta.I am sending a ajax request in the following manner.

```
   $.ajax("login", {
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(authData),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            async: true
          });
```

I am firing this request on button click.This same request is giving different response when i am  doing it locally (`http://localhost/myApplicationName`) and when i am doing on hosted website (`http://myCompany.com`).I am expecting the Bad Request(400) with some additional info(shown in figure 1) in  response for this request.Its working fine locally(shown in figure 1) ,but on deployed website i am getting string "Bad Request" in response with status 400(shown in figure 2) .Following is the response i am getting locally.

[image: local response]

And response for the same from deployed website

[image]

I tried to figure out this issue but could not reach at any conclusion.Is this the issue with the deployment or am i making some mistake in error handling ?

Comment: Is the URL local ? ie on the same domain ?

Comment: URL is not local.Its on other domain (http://domainname/login) which is hosted on other server.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log on the server? How are you hosting it? What's the IIS log saying?

Comment: I am hosting it by adding a website to Site node in IIS.Are there any additional steps for hosting RESTful websites?

This is the IIS log I got. 
`2012-03-12 04:52:56 192.168.2.2 POST /login - 80 - 192.168.2.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+rv:10.0.2)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/10.0.2 400 0 0 1881`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some web search on this issue and found a similar post on https://groups.google.com/d/msg/openrasta/UKyQSNjkp34/Lm8jqzawm8MJ
. 
Found the solution for the issue by putting this in web.config.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough">
 <clear />
</httpErrors>
```